# Could Anybody explain this Swift Code Regarding Option

Tags: swift

Today I read a code like this, which made me feel confused. What does the question mark after the argument "error" mean?

```
if error? == nil {
    self.updateDate(NSDate())
    self.updateImage(originalPrice, newPrice: price!)
    self.updatePrice(price!)
  }
```

Edited: The definition of error is from here

```
public func requestPrice(completion: PriceRequestCompletionBlock)

public typealias PriceRequestCompletionBlock = (price: NSNumber?, error: NSError?) -> ()

tracker.requestPrice { (price, error) -> () in
  if error? == nil {
    self.updateDate(NSDate())
    self.updateImage(originalPrice, newPrice: price!)
    self.updatePrice(price!)
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the `error` variable defined, and what value is assigned to it?

Comment: @MartinR Hi, Martin I had just added some more code, hope this will help you. I am confused with the error's question mark. Is it used to indicated it is a optional type? or to unwrap error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question mark is used for [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496) unwrapping.

But in this case it does nothing.

Comment: Perfectly accurate. In fact, using the question mark here is wrong, but there is evidently also no penalty for it. Perhaps there should be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that it is ok to use question mark after optional type variable? Could you give me some examples of use case that use question mark to unwrap? I knew we could use ! to unwrap optional type variable.

Comment: error? == nil is equivalent to error == nil. I'd suggest using second version because it's more clear.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift the variables can't be nil...unless you specify this possibility in the type definition. In your case, the request completion block can return an error...or can be nil if everything was fine.

Here is a link to Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1126

In your if statement, the question mark does nothing. You can remove it.

Comment: Irrelevant and misleading. We know that this value is an `NSError?`. The question is why it is being followed with a question mark in the expression `if error? == nil`. The answer is that it should not be.

Comment: Maybe @liyansong didn't know it. I only wanted to explain the reason of setting an optional type, in fact I was editing the answer to add the reason you answered. Does my response deserve a negative vote? I don't think so